# Error getting token price using Jupiter API in Python

Tags: solana-program, python, jupiter

I am trying to fetch the price of a token across multiple decentralized exchanges (DEXs) on the Solana blockchain using the Jupiter API in Python. However, I am encountering the following error: I have installed the `jupiter_python_sdk` library and updated it to the latest version using `pip install --upgrade jupiter-python-sdk`. I have also tried using different methods like `get_price`, `fetch_price`, and `price`, but they all result in similar AttributeError.

````
```
Error getting token price: 'Jupiter' object has no attribute 'price'
```



Here's the relevant code snippet:

```python

def __init__(self):
    self.solana_client = Client("https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com")
    self.wallet_private_key = os.getenv('')
    self.jupiter = Jupiter(self.solana_client, self.wallet_private_key)


async def get_token_price(self, token_mint_address):
    try:
        # Fetch the best price across multiple DEXs using Jupiter's price method
        price_response = await self.jupiter.price(
            inputMint=token_mint_address,  # The mint address of the token you want to sell
            outputMint="So11111111111111111111111111111111111111112",  # The mint address of Solana (SOL)
            amount=1,  # The amount of tokens to sell (in the token's decimal units)
            slippage=1,  # The maximum slippage percentage you are willing to accept
        )
        best_price = price_response['data']['price']
        print(f"Best price for token {token_mint_address}: {best_price} SOL")  # Print the best price
        return best_price
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error getting token price: {e}")
        return None
```
````

I have initialized the `Jupiter` object with the correct parameters, including the Solana client and the wallet private key.
I have also tried using the `route` method instead of `price`, but it doesn't seem to work either.I would appreciate any help in resolving this issue and successfully fetching the token price using the Jupiter API in Python. If you need any additional information or code snippets, please let me know.

Potential fixes or suggestions I have considered:
1. Checking if there are any missing or incorrect parameters being passed to the Jupiter API methods.
2. Exploring alternative methods or endpoints provided by the Jupiter API for fetching token prices.
3. Verifying if the `jupiter_python_sdk` library is compatible with the current version of the Jupiter API.
4. Investigating if there are any known issues or bugs with the `jupiter_python_sdk` library or the Jupiter API itself.